# Google Analytics, adding TrackEvent for multiple anchor links for PDFs

Tags: jquery, pdf, google-analytics

I'm stumped on one task I am trying to do. I am not an expert on JS or Jquery and can only use it on a rudimentary level.

Basically within a website, there are multiple anchor links that links to a PDF file (over 800 of them in fact).

I need to throw a Google Analytics trackEvent on each of these using:

```
onclick=”pageTracker._trackEvent(‘category’,’action’, ‘label’);”
```

inside each anchor tag.

Now rather than going through 800+ anchor tags and adding this one by one, I should just run a script that will do it for all of them that links to a PDF.

```
$('a[href$=.pdf]').on('click', function() {

onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('category','action', 'label');"

});
```

Now the part that Im stuck in. How do I get jquery to use the names of the PDF files as the "action" (basically name.pdf without the ".pdf"), and how would I use the anchor text as the "label"?

```
<a href="name.pdf">label</a>
```

Again, Im terrible at JS or Jquery haha, if anyone knows from the top of their head how to grab those following strings for this task it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector for the PDFs should be

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]') //with double quotes
```

(Note: do all the below within your click function)

To get just the name of the selected PDF, you can try

```
var fileNamePath = $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('href'); // gets full path name of selected file
var fileNameIndex = fileNamePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1; // returns number of characters from beginning of string up to the last / plus 1 since indexing starts at 0
var fileName = fileNamePath.substr(fileNameIndex); // return just part of the string after the last /
```

To get just the filename without extensoin

```
var fileNameNoExtension = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Question: why don't you just use "click" as an action (since actions are typically verbs), and then the filename as the label?

Comment: Yeah I changed it to .click after I posted this haha. Just realized I could've made it easier.

Anyway thanks for showing me how to grab the PDF names. It worked :D

Comment: @YanZ Hi, if you have resolved this issue, please mark as answered. Thanks!